# Confluent Cloud with MongoDB sink connect is not working

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, sink

I'm trying to connectting confluent kafka connect with mongodb sink,but its not working as expected, it throws null pointer exception.

My confluent development environment are running in GCP VM instance.

And installed "confluent-hub install mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:latest"

Below are my sink configuration.

```
{
 "name": "today-menu-sink",
 "config": {    
      "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "topics":"newuser",
      "connection.uri":"mongodb+srv://*********************.mongodb.net",
      "database":"BigBoxStore",
      "collection":"users",
      "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable":false,
      "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url" : "http://*******:8081" ,
      "value.converter.schemas.enable":true
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue - did you resolve in the end?

Comment: @DavidWadge, Not yet, I have tired no of times, but no luck.

Comment: I've raised a Jira issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/KAFKA-178

Comment: I am also having the same issue even i could connect my local db. How could you solve it?